# An error, im trying to make a function that process a person's symptoms and then store it inside a vector string as "Y" or "N" and i get this

Tags: c++, vector

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

string disease(vector<string> symptom, vector<string> name, int patientnum){
    string holder;
    cout << "is " << name[patientnum] << " experiencing  " << symptom[patientnum] << " Y/N";
    cin  >> holder;
    if(holder == "Y" || holder == "y"){
        return symptom.push_back("Y");
    }
    else if(holder == "N" || holder == "n"){
        return symptom.push_back("N");
    }
    else{
        cout <<"Please input Y/N" << endl;
        cout <<"Program exiting...";
    }
}

int main()
{
    vector<string> dry, sneeze, namex;
    int patientn = 0;
    string input;
    while(patientn < 2){
        cout << "Name: ";
        cin  >> input;
        namex.push_back(input);
        disease(dry[patientn], namex[patientn], patientn);
        patientn++;
    }
    
    for(patientn=0; patientn<namex.size(); patientn++){
        cout << namex[patientn] << " is experiencing dry cough = " << dry[patientn] << endl;
        cout << namex[patientn] << " is experiencing sneezing = " << sneeze[patientn] << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is the error im getting

```
error: could not convert ‘symptom.std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back, std::allocator > >(std::basic_string(((const char*)"Y"), std::allocator()))’ from ‘void’ to ‘std::string {aka std::basic_string}’
```

Im a freshmen in IT, so im sorry if my logic for making this program is stupid, and my variables naming are confusing.

So in the while loop im asking for a name and then storing it inside a name vector and then i call the function to ask for an input. "

```
cout <<"Is " << name << " experiecing " << symptom; //something like this but i also use an int patientnum to get the name[patientnum]
```

and then get y/n as the answer.
Then i make an if that accepts uppercase or lowercase answer and return symptom.push_back "Y" or "N"

and the for loop on the bottom is to print the name and then Y/N

Or can you guys suggest me a better way of doing this, im willing to learn anything.

Comment: Unrelated: `string disease(vector<string> symptom, vector<string> name, int patientnum)` passes by value. so `symptom` and `name` are copies. That means `symptom.push_back("Y");` modifies a copy, not the original, and the changes made will not be  seen back in main.

Comment: `push_back` returns nothing, so you can't `return symptom.push_back("Y");`. Not sure what you're trying to return there, so I can't give any suggestions on how to fix it. Anyway, that's the cause of the error message you're asking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the function to void, since you don't want to return anything from it.

```
void disease(vector<string> symptom, vector<string> name, int patientnum){
    string holder;
    cout << "is " << name[patientnum] << " experiencing  " << symptom[patientnum] << " Y/N";
    cin  >> holder;
    if(holder == "Y" || holder == "y"){
        symptom.push_back("Y");
    }
    else if(holder == "N" || holder == "n"){
        symptom.push_back("N");
    }
    else{
        cout <<"Please input Y/N" << endl;
        cout <<"Program exiting...";
    }
}
```

Unfortunately that's only one of many issues with your code.

Incidentally if you spend some time choosing logical and meaningful names for your functions and variables you will find the programming easier. Funny that. Half the battle with programming is thinking clearly about what you are doing, and meaningless or arbitrary names show that you aren't thinking clearly.